# Wie formuliere ich eine Frage über (A unterscheidet sich in B und C)

Tags: question, interrogative

Nehmen wir an, ich soll folgenden Satz in eine Frage umformulieren:
„Bei Privatkrediten werden Personalkredite und Anschaffungskredite unterschieden.“
Lautet die Frage dann „Worin ...“, „Wovon ...“ oder „Wie werden Privatkredite unterschieden?“

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da es offenbar darum geht, nach der Unterteilung in Personalkredite und Anschaffungskredite zu fragen, liegt eine Formulierung nahe wie

> Welche Formen unterscheidet man bei Privatkrediten?

Eventuell gibt es eine etablierte Bezeichnung, die man anstelle von "Formen" verwenden sollte, z. B. "welche Arten", "welche Typen" usw.

Comment: "Welche (Unter-)Kategorien" war das, was mir beim Lesen der Frage spontan in den Sinn kam.

Answer (score 2):

"Wie werden Privatkredite unterschieden" und "Worin unterscheiden sich Privatkredite" ist korrekt.
Oder auch "worin unterscheiden sich Personalkredite und Anschaffungskredite?" ist korrekt.

"Wovon unterscheiden sich Privatkredite" ist auch ein korrekter Satz, aber dabei geht es dann um Privatkredite und etwas anderes. Als Beispiel "Wovon unterscheiden sich Privatkredite? Von Äpfeln, denn Kredite wachsen nicht auf Bäumen".

Answer (score 0):

Weitere Möglichkeiten:

> - Welche Arten von Privatkrediten unterscheidet man?
> - Welche Privatkreditarten unterscheidet man?

Etwas kürzere Alternativen:

> - Welche Arten von Privatkrediten gibt es?
> - Welche Privatkreditarten gibt es?

Answer (score -1):

> Bei Privatkrediten werden Personalkredite und Anschaffungskredite unterschieden.

Sagt nur, dass sich die zwei Dinge unterscheiden. Der Text muss im Weiteren deswegen nicht notgedrungen auf die Unterschiede eingehen. Möchte man das, so sollte man schreiben:

> Was unterscheidet Personalkredite und Anschaffungskredite [voneinander]?